# Convert timestamp to datetime in mysql (without php)

Tags: php, mysql, bulk

```
SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`,"%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s") AS a 
FROM `tb_backup`;
```

created_at is timestamp string row name
created_at=1668049479
a=2022-11-10 08:34:39

you can use inside stored procedure

Comment: 0


SELECT *,FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s") AS a FROM tb_backup;

created_at is timestamp string row name | created_at=1668049479 | a=2022-11-10 08:34:39

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Remove format from the function arguments - it is excess in your case. I.e. simply `SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at) AS a FROM tb_backup;`. https://dbfiddle.uk/jCObtYkP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert timestamp to datetime in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql)